# User Defined Indirect Function with COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, countif

I am trying to create a UDF to replace the INDIRECT function for use in the COUNTIFS function to allow dynamic ranges.

Goal:

Current:

```
=countifs(indirect([cell reference to named range],[criteria1]...)
```

I am trying to achieve:

```
=countifs(INDIRECTVBA([cell reference to named range],[criteria1...)
```

The function returns #VALUE at the moment.

Here is my VBA:

```
Public Function INDIRECTVBA(ref_text As String)
    INDIRECTVBA = Range(ref_text)
End Function
```

The ref_text argument would be a reference to a cell in which a VLOOKUP is dynamically listing a named range based on user selection elsewhere.

My first guess is a data type mismatch but I am out of ideas.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Jordan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a Variant value instead of a Range.

This would give an error because `CountIf` is expecting a Range in its first argument and not a Variant value.

If you want to return a range add `As Range` to your function declaration and use a [Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement) statement.

```vb
Public Function INDIRECTVBA(ref_text As String) As Range
    Set INDIRECTVBA = Range(ref_text)
End Function
```

Because you omit Set the compiler is interpreting it as a [Let](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/let-statement) statement. Without `As Range` in the function declaration, it is defaulting to `As Variant`. So the function is retrieving the value within the Range instead of returning the Range itself (Range objects give their `Range.Value` property by default when in `Let` statements).

I'm not too educated in CS, so this answer might be inaccurate. I genuinely appreciate learning more when people correct me.